# How to show popup on same page after data submission

Tags: php, database, html

I have this html form

```html
<form class="form" method="post" action="data.php">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name" required="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone" required="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" placeholder="Email ID" name="email" id="email" required="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <!--<input class="form-control input-lg option" type="date" name="date" value="Date" id="date" required="">-->
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg option" name="date" Placeholder="Date" id="datepicker">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control input-lg option" name="time" id="time" style="padding-left: 10px;color:darkgray;">
        <option>Time Slot</option>
        <option>10:00-11:00</option>
        <option>11:00-12:00</option>
        <option>12:00-13:00</option>
        <option>13:00-14:00</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-top:10px; padding: 5px 16px;" type="submit" value="BOOK ">
```

Here is code of data.php

```html
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (name,phone,email,date,time)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]',  '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[time]')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
}
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

This code shows a pop up on same window with ugly format and after click on ok it shows blank page with ..../data.php url.  I want to redirect on same page.

And can i change popup style. I want to show popup in mid of the page.

Please help to solve these issues.. I am newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the location of the alert-popup. You need to open a popup via `window.open`.
Use this below updated code to redirect back to your required page.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (name,phone,email,date,time)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]',  '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[time]')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
{
    header('Location:index.php?success=1');
}
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Replace `yourpage.php` in header function with your actual name of the page.
Rename your `index.html` to `index.php` and make these changes to the index file.

```
<?php
$get = (isset($_GET['success'])) ? $_GET['success'] : '';
if((!empty($get)) && ($get == 1))
{
    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
}
?>

<form class="form" method="post" action="data.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" placeholder="Email ID" name="email" id="email" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--<input class="form-control input-lg option" type="date" name="date" value="Date" id="date" required="">-->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg option" name="date" Placeholder="Date" id="datepicker">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control input-lg option" name="time" id="time" style="padding-left: 10px;color:darkgray;">
                          <option>Time Slot</option>
                          <option>10:00-11:00</option>
                          <option>11:00-12:00</option>
                          <option>12:00-13:00</option>
                          <option>13:00-14:00</option>
                         </select>
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-top:10px; padding: 5px 16px;" type="submit" value="BOOK ">
```

I have also modified the data.php file again, so be sure to use the updated code.

Comment: After submission it takes me index.html file. Data is fetching properly but no pop up is coming

Comment: Hi akshay. It implemented thanks. Please tell me if i want to show a centered popup on page then what i have to do

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp Have a look here to see examples.